# Mitmproxy: Certification Errors with Upstream Server

Tags: mitmproxy

I am trying to split up my Network traffic into two streams using Mitmproxy.
I therefore have one incoming proxy that accepts traffic from my IPhone and I am using two secondary Proxies to which the Traffic is forwarded. I start the three instances like this:

> mitmproxy --mode upstream 127.0.0.1:8083 -s mitmRoot.py --ssl-insecure

> mitmproxy --listen-port 8083 --ssl-insecure

> mitmproxy --listen-port 8082 --ssl-insecure

I am using the following, very simple Python script to route the traffic:

```
class mitmRoot:

    def request(self, flow: mitmproxy.http.HTTPFlow):
        if "github.com" in str(flow.request.url):
            flow.live.change_upstream_proxy_server(("localhost", 8082))

addons = [
    mitmRoot()
]
```

Now everything works perfectly fine if I am using only one proxy without any upstream Proxy. I have installed the certificate on the Phone and I can open any website in the browser

However if I add the two upstream proxies I see start seeing certification errors,
mostly for IPhone related stuff:

```
clientdisconnect
clientconnect
Certificate verification error for gateway.icloud.com: self signed certificate in certificate chain (errno: 19, depth: 1)
Ignoring server verification error, continuing with connection
Client Handshake failed. The client may not trust the proxy's certificate for gateway.icloud.com.
```

Interestingly I can still establish connections to websites except the ones where I am switching the upstream server. So in this example I am not able to open github.com.

The input proxy now throws cert errors for github.com as well, while the upstream proxy that should be getting the traffic (the one on port 8082) does not see any traffic at all I also see some clientconnect/ clientdisconnect messages in the stream:

```
https://github.com/
clientconnect
clientconnect
Certificate verification error for github.com: self signed certificate in certificate chain (errno: 19, depth: 1)
Ignoring server verification error, continuing with connection
Certificate verification error for keyvalueservice.icloud.com: self signed certificate in certificate chain (errno: 19, depth: 1)
Ignoring server verification error, continuing with connection
Client Handshake failed. The client may not trust the proxy's certificate for keyvalueservice.icloud.com
```

I have tried different configuration options, for "--set add_upstream_certs_to_client=true" but so far I am not able to set this up right.

It seems like there is some kind of configuration issue but I don't yet see why it is happening.

Thank You for your help!

Comment: Apple's own services often use certificate pinning (especially those that use according to mitmproxy "self-signed" certificates) so to my knowledge the only way to allow such traffic is to bypass such hosts using the `--ignore-hosts` option.

Comment: That is what I was thinking as well but then why does it work with a single proxy instance with no upstream proxies attached?